# Does MongoID do a separate query for .count(true)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have a ruby on rails 3 project in which I query for a certain number of objects by using a .limit(3) . Then, in my view, I loop through these objects. After that, if there are 3 objects in the view, I display a "load more" button. Here is the view code:

```
<% @objects.each do |object| %>
  <%= render object._type.pluralize.underscore + '/teaser', :object => object %>
<% end %>
<% if @objects.size(true) == 3 %>
  #load more link here
<% end %>
```

The `size(true)` is passed a boolean to ensure that mongoID takes into account the .limit and .offset on my query (otherwise it returns the total number of objects that matched, regardless of the limit / offset). Here are the relevant development log lines:

```
MONGODB project_development['system.indexes'].insert([{:name=>"_public_id_1", :ns=>"project_development.objects", :key=>{"_public_id"=>1}, :unique=>true}])
MONGODB project_development['objects'].find({:deleted_at=>{"$exists"=>false}}).limit(3).sort([[:created_at, :desc]])
#some rendering of views
MONGODB project_development['system.indexes'].insert([{:name=>"_public_id_1", :ns=>"project_development.objects", :key=>{"_public_id"=>1}, :unique=>true}])
MONGODB project_development['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"objects", "query"=>{:deleted_at=>{"$exists"=>false}}, "limit"=>3, "fields"=>nil})
```

My question is: does MongoID do a separate query for my `@objects.size(true)`? I imagine the `['$cmd']` might indicate otherwise, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, there was a [pull request](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/1082) month ago to add aliases for :size, :length to :count to avoid re-running queries. You can check that.

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks like you were right. Much appreciated!